# (doc, term, count) record list as D×T sparse document–term matrix + string index

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, information-retrieval

I have a tuple representation of document–term counts as a list of records (obtained from an external file). For the sake of example, let's assume it is stored in an np.array like this:

```
data = [
    ('doc1', 'the', 1), ('doc1', 'man', 1),
    ('doc2', 'the', 2), ('doc2', 'more', '1'), ('doc2', 'better', 2)]
dt = [('doc', '<U20'), ('term', '<U20'), ('freq', int)]
doc_term_counts = np.array(data, dtype=dt)
```

The task is to obtain a sparse matrix (CSC matrix preferably) containing docs as rows, terms as columns and counts as cell values, while also keeping a mapping between doc and term names indices into strings. Is there any elegant solution? CountVectorizer from sklearn assumes that the input is shaped as documents, each being a list of terms, here the representation is different.

EDIT:
The following code does the job but it relies on pure-Python dicts and manual string indexing. Is there a more scipyish alternative?

```
d2idx = {}
t2idx = {}
idx2d = []
idx2t = []

for doc, term, cnt in doc_term_counts:
    if doc not in d2idx:
        d2idx[doc] = len(idx2d)
        idx2d.append(doc)
    if term not in t2idx:
        t2idx[term] = len(idx2t)
        idx2t.append(term)

dt_mat = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(
    (
        doc_term_counts['freq'],
        (
            np.vectorize(lambda doc: d2idx[doc])(doc_term_counts['doc']),
            np.vectorize(lambda term: t2idx[term])(doc_term_counts['term']))),
    shape=(len(idx2d), len(idx2t)))

print(dt_mat.toarray())
```

Comment: What did you try so far and what error do you get? Try to include a [mcve]

Comment: @Francesco No errors there, just added a working solution to the question. I'm seeking a more elegant one to learn the scipy way!

Comment: You should then use [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of SO